# How prove this $\angle PK_{3}B=\angle BK_{3}Q$

Tags: geometry

**Question:**

> three circles $K_{1},K_{2},K_{3}$ are tangent to each other,(Circles $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ are externally tangent at a point $T$),Denote by $L_{1}$ is the exterior common tangent of the circles $K_{1},K_{2}$,meets $K_{3}$ in $P,Q$,and Denote by $L_{2}$ is the common tangent at $T$ meet $K_{3}$ in $B$.

show that:

> $$\angle PK_{3}B=\angle BK_{3}Q$$

[image]

maybe this is famous thereom?  if someone have see it?can you link .Thank you

Comment: Do you want to prove it or to know (the name of) the theorem?

Comment: Yes,@QuangHoang,Thank you

Comment: @chinamath: Answering an “either … or …” kind of question with “yes” is not exactly helpful. Do you want a proof (as your title indicates), or do you want a name (as your last paragraph indicates), or do you want both, or do you want either? Please edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the angle-preservation property of the circular inversion: we just need to show that the tangent to $K3$ in $B$ is always parallel to $L1$.

Let $U$ be the projection of $T$ on $L1$ and $K4$ be the circle with center $T$ and radius $TU$.

Let $P^{-1}$ denotes the circular inversion of $P$ with respect to $K4$.

$K1^{-1}$ and $K2^{-1}$ are two lines, both parallel to $L2$, so $K3^{-1}$ is congruent to $L1^{-1}$ (it is just a translated copy of $L1^{-1}$ along the direction of $K1^{-1}$).

This gives that for any possible $K3$, the diameter of $K3^{-1}$ is constant, and the tangent $\tau$ to $K3^{-1}$ in $B^{-1}$ always has the same direction. In particular, $\tau$ and $L1$ cut $L2$ with opposite angles; moreover, the center of the circle $K5$ through $T$ that is tangent to $\tau$ lies in the intersection of $TU$ with the line through $B^{-1}$ orthogonal to $\tau$.

By inverting a second time, this gives that the tangent to $K3$ in $B$ is parallel to $L1$, as wanted.

[image: Angle-preserving property of the circular inversion]

(*In this figure, $K3$ does not meet $L1$ in order to avoid an even messier configuration. 
We just provided a visual evidence that the tangent in $B$ to $K3$ is parallel to $L1$*.)